# Finding a property in a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm creating a JSON object like

```
tags = {"jon":["beef","pork"],"jane":["chicken","lamb"]};
```

which was generated using php from an array like

```
$arr = array(
        'jon' => array('beef', 'pork'),
        'jane' => array('chicken', 'lamb')
       );
$tags = json_encode($arr);
```

And I want to check if something is in one or the other. None of these seem to work, but something like

```
if('lamb' in tags.jane)) {
    console.log('YES');
} else {
    console.log('NO');
}
```

writes **NO** to the console

```
if('foo' in tags.jane)) {
    console.log('YES');
} else {
    console.log('NO');
}
```

also writes **NO** to the console

so looking at

```
typeof(tags.jane);
```

it shows it's an `"object"` but

```
console.log(tags);
```

shows the following:

```
Object
jane: Array[2]
    0: "chicken"
    1: "lamb"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
jon: Array[2]
    0: "beef"
    1: "pork"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

so i thought maybe `tags.jane` may actually be an array and tried

```
if($.inArray('lamb', tags.jane)) {
    console.log('YES');
} else {
    console.log('NO');
}
```

which writes **YES** to the console but

```
if($.inArray('foo', tags.jane)) {
    console.log('YES');
} else {
    console.log('NO');
}
```

also writes **YES** to the console.

Am I incorrectly building the JSON Object? Not targeting the value(s) properly? Any advice is greatly appreciated. If this would be easier as an array instead of an object, I have full control to change it. I'm just a bit stumped at how I should treat this.

Comment: use JSON.parse( jsonString ) to convert the server response to a javascript object.

Comment: +1 for a *thorough* demonstration of what you tried.

Comment: sorry i didn't mention i was parsing the JSON in the js, but either way Sergio (and others) gave me what I needed. Thanks all! Out of curiosity, why are tags.jane and tags.jon arrays instead of "nested objects" is that just not possible in JSON? when i started this i was thinking i'd do a check like if(tags.jane.chicken) expecting it to return true or false if the property existed. i obviously need to do some reading on JSON objects. :P Thanks again to all those that chimed in.

Comment: @amnotiam: if only there were more questions like this :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Agreed. @@ocergynohtna: JSON has 2 data structures. One is an ordered list *(an Array)* where the keys are excluded in the markup, because they're implicitly 0-based indices. The other is an collection of key/value pairs, where the keys can be any string value. To get the `tags.jane.chicken` behavior, you'd need to use `chicken` as a key, and choose `true` (or another truthy value) as the value, and use the `{}` syntax for object notation. `{"jon":{"beef":true,"pork":true},"jane":{"chicken":true,"lamb":true}}`

Comment: thanks guys. i try to be as thorough as I can. not only for me, but so that if another dev is looking for a solution similar to this, it should get returned easier in a query. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns -1 when element is not found. That's `true` value from the POV of Javascript. Try this:

```
if($.inArray('foo', tags.jane) != -1) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second set of answers are the way you should go. However, $.inArray returns an index, not a boolean. Any non-zero integer is true, which means when `foo` is not found, it returns -1 which evaluates to `true` and prints **YES**.

Similarly, `$.inArray('chicken', tags.jane)` would return `0` and cast to false, which is also not the answer you want.

Instead, use `$.inArray('foo', tags.jane) !== -1` as your condition.

Answer (score 2):

tags.name will give you the array for that person. So `$.inArray("chicken",tags.jane)` would see if "chicken" is in jane's tags array. If it's not, you'd get -1, otherwise you'd it's position in the array (using your example, this would return zero, the first array element).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the keyword in for the wrong reason.
The statement ( prop 'in' obj ) checks to see if the object(associated array) has a property with the value of prop.
Since you're using the 'in' keyword on an array, then false is going to be returned because tags.jane is an array with indexes and not an associated array with properties.

If you want to know was values are in the array then loop through and compare.
If you want to use the 'in' keyword then convert your array to an object like so.

```
    tags = {};
    // old code
    tags.jane = ['lamb', 'food']; 
console.log(('lamb' in tags.jane) === false )
    // new code
    tags.jane = {
       'lamb':1,
        'food':1
    }
console.log(('lamb' in tags.jane) === true )
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

you can not use

```
if('foo' in tags.jane))
```

it should be used as

```
if (1 in tags.jane)
```

if you want to check 'foo' is in tags.jane, try this

```
var inIt = (function() {
    var inIt = false;
    tags.jane.forEach(function(item) {
        inIt = inIt || 'foo' == item;
    });
    return inIt;
})();
```